# Is correct way to define the JPQL with same alias name?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using eclipse link jpa as my ORM. I am creating query based on inputs passed. Dynamic where clause generation. everything is fine until i had requirement of writing sub query.

for Example

```
select emp from Employee emp where emp.empId IN ( select emp.dept from Employee emp)
```

if you observe my above JPQL query i have provided same alias name "emp" for table objects. does it cause any issues. I am able to run the query without any issues.

i can simply say emp1 and emp2. Is correct way to define the JPQL with same alias name?

**UPDATE**

I have tried both ways one JPQL query with same alias name and another query with different name. Both are working fine. IF you want more control on your query i suggest go for different alias name.

Comment: that is not an SQL query, it is JPQL. Perhaps clarify your question with what you actually mean ...

Comment: that's is not a native (i.e SQL) query. It's JPQL. No idea what you mean by "cause any problem in the future" ...

Comment: sorry.it is JPQL. i am using this a as part of entityManager.createQuery(); since i am using tableObject same( here emp), does this emp cause any issue. since creation is not in our control.

Comment: Is correct way to define the JPQL with same alias name? this is what i should have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the parent query from a subquery in either SQL or JPQL, they are completely isolated. So I can't see any issues with what you are doing.  Have you tried it?

Having said that, you query does not make sense.  You are checking if the employee Id is in a list of departments.  I would suggest this is the issue you are having.

Comment: thank you. it is just sampple JPQL. In real scenario it is working without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both ways, one JPQL query with same alias name and another query with different name. Both are working fine. IF you want more control on your query i suggest go for different alias name. Since i am creating dynamic where clause based on the inputs passed.